# Using session tickets (RFC 5077) on a custom client

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

I have an HTTPS server, serving custom clients written in C++ (using POCO::Net and OpenSSL). Do I need to do something actively to enable session tickets on the client, or will it respond properly just by the fact I am using the latest OpenSSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the client is, in fact, using TLS session tickets. It is quite possible to turn off ticket-based session resumption in custom clients using OpenSSL APIs. For instance, [SSL_CTX_set_options](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html) supports the following option:

> SSL_OP_NO_TICKET
>
> Normally clients and servers will, where possible, transparently make use of RFC4507bis tickets for stateless session
>   resumption.
>   If this option is set, this functionality is disabled and tickets will
>   not be used by clients or servers.

If the client has explicitly turned off ticket-based resumption using the above-quoted option, it will not support TLS tickets.

Comment: Thanks. So, if a client wraps OpenSSL and does not use this flag, it should know what to do with tickets automatically. Cool.